# Echo two variables from array with formatting

Tags: zsh

My problem is: This code

```
#!/bin/sh
[...]
formatedForArray="$foo - $bar\n"       
arrOne+=($formatedForArray)
  
echo -e ${arrOne[@]}
```

prints

```
foo1 content with spaces - bar1
 foo2 - bar2
 foo3 - bar3 content with spaces
```

which is almost what I really want:

```
foo1 content with spaces - bar1
foo2 - bar2
foo3 - bar3 content with spaces
```

I also tried printf

```
printf '%s\n' "${arrOne[@]}"
```

without the \n in formatedForArray, which will make a new line after every space it is processing

```
foo1
content
with
spaces
-
bar1
```

Am I lost, is there another way to achieve the output of "$foo - $bar" in one line, then linebreak? I'm on zsh, but under bash it gives me the same output.

Comment: Since you tagged this `zsh`, `formattedForArray="$foo - $bar"; ...;  print -l $arrOne`.

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating it.
Don't include the newline in the strings - add it with the printf later.
**DO** put quotes around your formatted string so that it adds the whole string as only *one* value when you add it into the array. You are adding a bunch at a time.

```
$: cat tst
for f in 1 2 3
do for b in 1 2 3
   do arrOne+=("foo$f - bar$b") # quotes when assigning to the array
   done
done
printf '%s\n' "${arrOne[@]}"

$: . tst
foo1 - bar1
foo1 - bar2
foo1 - bar3
foo2 - bar1
foo2 - bar2
foo2 - bar3
foo3 - bar1
foo3 - bar2
foo3 - bar3
```

Without those quotes, `"foo$f - bar$b"` is being added as `"foo$f" "-" "bar$b"`.

Comment: Thank you, this does not work in my script, but your code works perfectly in a test script. Will investigate further, there must be something messing up the new line.

Comment: Feel free to elaborate the problem, maybe we can still help.